# How to call c# function in html5app in windows phone?

Tags: html, windows-phone-8

I have to create html5 application in visual studio 2013 for windows phone 8.1.

How to call c# function in html page - javascript?

Any idea or link should be help me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways of doing it. One of them is calling such C# functions through window.external.notify method and listening these calls in your C# back-end;

So your JS function in your HTML5 page will do sth like this, whenever you want to call a function:

```
 window.external.notify("SomeSpecificFunctionCall");
```

Then you will be listening such notifications in your C# code - where you host your browser control:

```
 private void Browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
        {                
            if (e.Value.StartsWith("SomeSpecificFunctionCall"))
            {               
                // Call your function here

            }                     
        }
```

Note that you can also invoke any kind of script with Browser.InvokeScript method in your HTML through C# code:

```
 Browser.InvokeScript("scriptName", parameters);
```

Comment: In the last part `Browser.InvokeScript` should be `webBrowser.InvokeScript` I guess.